# Disable re-queueing of failed Hangfire BackgroundJob

Tags: c#, hangfire

Is there a way to disable re-queueing of a failed Hangfire BackgroundJob?

We do not want the failed jobs to be executed again as this might cause issues.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Solved, using `[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]`

Comment: You may also add `OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete` to ignore them and do not blow up the "failed jobs" page.

Comment: This solution is what that docs say to do, but in practice, I don't see a difference in the running system.  My failed jobs retry themselves even when this attribute is on the method that I'm calling from my recurring Job.  Others seem to have the [same problem](http://discuss.hangfire.io/t/automaticretry-attempts-0-onattemptsexceeded-attemptsexceededaction-fail-is-not-working/648) too.

Comment: if using DI container you must put the attribute on the interface definition and not on the implementation. eg. `interface IMyService { [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)void MyMethod(); }`

Answer (score 30):

You can either annotate the method to run in the background with the following attribute:

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
```

Or set it globally:

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });
```

Comment: But how do you do this on a job-by-job basis? Say you want retries by defualy, but a job failed in an unrecoverable way and you don't want it to retry that specific job.

Answer (score 20):

**Important if using DI container with an interface, you must put the attribute on the interface definition**

```
public interface IDataUpdater
{
    [Hangfire.AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete)]
    void UpdateData();
}
```

Queue the job like this

```
Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IDataUpdater>(updater => updater.UpdateData(), Cron.Hourly);
```

Test it by just throwing any old exception within your implementation. If you've done it right you'll see this in the job history under 'deleted'.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Ran into this today but wanted to set the Retry Filter globally in a .NET API application.

The following worked...

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => {
            // Disable retry for failed jobs
            // https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/dealing-with-exceptions.html?highlight=retry
            configuration.UseFilter(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue and I was able to find a solution. Using a global filter was not an option for me. I'm using asp.net core and I have a simple fire and forget background job. For some reason the `AutomaticRetryAttribute` was being ignored. It turned out the way I was adding the job was the key to my solution. I had a similar code in my app that was causing the issue:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IMyJobService>(js => js.DoWork());
```

In my IMyJobService implementation I had the following code:

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
public void DoWork()
{
    // I'm working hard here
}
```

The solution that I came up with was:

```
public MyTestController
{
    private readonly IMyJobService _myJobService;

    public MyTestClass(IMyJobService myJobService)
    {
        _myJobService = myJobService;
    }

    public ActionResult Work()
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _myJobService.DoWork());
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Instead of relying on `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<T>` to inject my `IMyJobService` implementation I do it myself. That's basically it. I hope this will help someone.

Comment: I solved the same issue putting the AutomaticRetryAttribute on the method definition of the interface, not on the implemented one.